# Add labels to each ng-template

Tags: angular, ng-template

I'm trying to add *Labels* or *Names* for *each* of my `ng-template` and then save that *label* in a `property` and I'm not sure how to do this.

I would like to do this because, I want each `ng-template` associated with the correct *Label* when the list of `ng-template`s is iterated over.

**To Note:**
I am creating a reusable Tab component. The Tab component will hold the logic and the Parent component will hold the `ng-template`s since only the Parent knows what kind of templates it will need.

And each `ng-template` needs a tab label to go with it.

**Tried:**
I have tried adding `name = "Label 2"` to the `ng-template` but I don't think that did anything.

```
 <ng-template #temp1 name="Label 2"> <p>this is template 2</p> </ng-template>
```

**Goal:** I want to fill my `templates` property with an `object` like this.

```
let templates = {tempLabel: 'Label 2', template: 'temp1'}
```

I already got the `template: temp1` part, I just need the `tempLabel: 'Label 2` part of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom directive that will store label and template itself, like this:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appLabel]'
})
export class LabelDirective {
  constructor(public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) { }
  @Input('appLabel') label = '';
}
```

And inject it into component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChildren(LabelDirective) templates: QueryList<LabelDirective> 
}
```

Here's the AppComponent template:

```html
<ng-template appLabel="label 1"></ng-template>
<ng-template appLabel="label 2"></ng-template>
<ng-template appLabel="label 3"></ng-template>

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let t of templates">{{t.label}} - {{ t.templateRef }}</li>
</ul>
```

And here's the working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w8sd4y

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I edited my original question to provide further clarification. I tried your solution, but nothing was logging when I looped over `templates` in my parent component.

Comment: Perhaps, you are passing templates via `ng-content`. Try replacing `ViewChildren` with `ContentChildren` (it will be populated after `ngAfterContentInit` lifecycle hook - https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't using `ng-content` but did try your next suggestion but still no luck. If you'd like, you can view my code in this image since I cannot write my code in this comment.

https://postimg.cc/DWBrJ3rC


https://i.postimg.cc/85VtY1jV/tab-panel-code.jpg

Comment: That's weird, `ContentChildren` should work here. I have no clue, but try this updated example to resemble your case: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w8sd4y

Comment: Thank you, I tried your updated example. The directive for some reason just doesn't seem to be grabbing the `templateRef`s in the parent. I believe I'm doing exactly what you're doing in your example. I've uploaded an image of my code here. And I tried it with `ViewChildren` and `ContentChildren`.

https://postimg.cc/KkL88Ncv

Comment: This is what my original code was which did grab the `ng-template`s and push them into an array. But I still don't know how to add a `label` to each `ng-template` to use for the Tab Label.

https://postimg.cc/vD1Xz2XS